# Where i can download gcc and glib for Cygwin?

Tags: c++, c, cygwin, cross-compiling

I'm writting application for embedded system. Where i can download gcc version 3.4.3 with glib version 2.3.4 for Cygwin ?

I have download cygwin-gcc-3.3.6-glibc-2.3.2-linux.tar.bz2 but this version isn't suitable for me...

Comment: Why isn't that version suitable?

Comment: When i run my application, which copmile upnder cygwin i have the following message: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file of directory

Comment: do you want a cross compiler for a different target platform (it's not clear whether Cygwin runs on the embedded platform you mention) or to compile for the environment you run cygwin on ? If it's the latter, have you tried rerunning the Cygwin setup utility and select gcc in the list of packages to install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes linux distributions have a 'compat' packages which make older libraries available. Try searching cygwin for the version of libstdc++ you're looking for.